# Spring Hibernate Saves/Commits Transaction whithout invoking Save method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using a Spring and Hibernate implementation of JPA.
In my service class I have a method as follows.

```
@Override
public String myMethod(String arg) throws Exception {
 MyObject obj = fetchFromDB();

 // Some code to update object.

 if(isSuccess){
    myObject.saveAndFlush();
 }
 else{
    return failure;
 }
}
```

For Some reason the changes are saved to Database even though am not saving the object.

Comment: Can we see the part where you're updating the object?

Comment: Its just inside boolean

if(success){
 org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository.saveAndFlush(myObject);
}

I see that the Update Queries in this case are logged once U exit from this method.

Comment: And Updates are simple...  no referenced or cascaded objects are saved...myObject is parent object... And I directly save that.

Answer (score 1):

When you fetch the object from database, it is *attached* to hibernate session. Every change you make to an attached object is persisted without the need to explicitly call `save` on the object.

Quote from [the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-overview)

> Hibernate will detect any changes made to an object in persistent state and synchronize the state with the database when the unit of work completes.

In your case, if possible you should do all the updates to the object inside `isSuccess` block.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your full implementation, I suspect this is saving because your object is in the managed state.

From the [documentation for Java EE 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html#bnbrc):

> Managed entity instances have a persistent identity and are associated with a persistence context.

And then, when it goes on to [explain what that means](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html#bnbrf)...

> The state of persistent entities is synchronized to the database when the transaction with which the entity is associated commits. If a managed entity is in a bidirectional relationship with another managed entity, the data will be persisted, based on the owning side of the relationship.

So if you have a managed entity (meaning, you used `EntityManager` to find it and you did not call `detach()`), when you commit your transaction, changes to the entity are persisted.